# Open screen from script in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm writing a react-native app that in one of scenarios has to show screen with details on event, that is triggered by background js script.
App uses NavigationContainer, the screen I need to pop up is Profile, where I need to pass custom parameters.

```
const [winId, setWinId] = useState(null);
 return (
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Straightforward navigation does not work from background script, says it should be run only from inside NavigationContainer. Pseudo-code for this approach:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
navigator = useNavigation()
navigator.navigate("Profile")
```

So I am creating a state variable winId, which will be updated with setter `setWinId` from background script, but how do I perform navigation to screen as a result of event?

The navigation to Screen can be done from inside other screen using navigation object passed there. So I can spawn screen Notifications for this purpose, but now I need to pass winId to screen and trigger its re-render on each winId update. How can it be done?
Maybe I'm going a completely wrong path here? Maybe this can't be done with NavigationContainer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be one initial screen at least on your stack navigation.
It will be always running unless your app becomes in the background state or quiet. As I am seeing your code snippet it should be the notification screen. On the screen you can navigate to other screens with 'winId' param.
I am not sure how your background js works but in there you can dispatch 'setWinId' action or something else like setting value in sharing context with notification screen.

```
function Notifications() {
 // getting winId from the sharing context or redux
 const winId = ...
 useEffect(()=>{
  navigation.navigate('Profile', {winId})
 }, [winId])
}

function Profile({route}) {
 const {winId} = route.params
 useEffect(()=>{
  // do something needs to do by the changing value of winId
 }, [winId])
}
```